# AWS AppFlow - rename source field

Tags: amazon-web-services, salesforce, amazon-appflow

I have an AppFlow set up with Salesforce as the source and S3 as the destination. I am able to move *all* columns over by using a `Map_all` task type in the flow definition, and leaving the source fields empty.

However now I want to move just a few columns to S3, and rename them as well. I was trying to do something like this :

```
                                    "Tasks": [
                                        {
                                            "SourceFields": ["Website"],
                                            "DestinationField": "Website",
                                            "TaskType": "Map",
                                            "TaskProperties": {},
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "SourceFields": ["Account Name"],
                                            "DestinationField": "AccountName",
                                            "TaskType": "Map",
                                            "TaskProperties": {},
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "SourceFields": ["Account ID"],
                                            "DestinationField": "AccountId",
                                            "TaskType": "Map",
                                            "TaskProperties": {},
                                        }
                                    ],
```

but I get the error
`Create Flow request failed: [Task Validation Error: You must specify a projection task or a MAP_ALL task]`.

How can I select a few columns as well as rename them before moving them to S3 without resorting to something like Glue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out - first added a Projection task to fetch the fields needed, and then Map tasks, one per field being renamed

Comment: Can you share a code example with your solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
    tasks=[
        {
            "connectorOperator": {"Salesforce": "PROJECTION"},
            "sourceFields": ["Id", "Name"],
            "taskProperties": {},
            "taskType": "Filter",
        },
        {
            "connectorOperator": {"Salesforce": "NO_OP"},
            "destinationField": "Id",
            "sourceFields": ["Id"],
            "taskProperties": {
                "DESTINATION_DATA_TYPE": "string",
                "SOURCE_DATA_TYPE": "id",
            },
            "taskType": "Map",
        },
        {
            "connectorOperator": {"Salesforce": "NO_OP"},
            "destinationField": "Name",
            "sourceFields": ["Name"],
            "taskProperties": {
                "DESTINATION_DATA_TYPE": "string",
                "SOURCE_DATA_TYPE": "string",
            },
            "taskType": "Map",
        },
    ],
```

The above is the needed code.

And I did not find this information in AWS docs.

A trick is I have created a flow manually in AppFlow GUI with `Map fields directly` option in Step 3 `Edit data fields` and chose the wanted source fields.

After successful creation of the flow, I used
Appflow.Client.describe_flow(**kwargs),
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/appflow/client/describe_flow.html#describe-flow
which returned all the needful.

And here is the mapping:
[image]